# Is there a way to prevent Memory Leaks in a Derived Class without modifying the Base Class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, memory-leaks, virtual-functions

So I've got a base class that looks like this:

```
class base {
public:
    base() {
        std::cout << "We created a base!" << std::endl;
    }

    ~base() {
        std::cout << "We destroyed a base!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I have a derived class that looks like this:

```
class leaks_memory : public base {
public:
    leaks_memory(size_t count) :
    memory(new int[count]), size_of_memory(count)
    {
        announce();
    }

    leaks_memory(const leaks_memory & lm) :
    leaks_memory(lm.size_of_memory)
    {
        std::copy(lm.memory, lm.memory + size_of_memory, memory);
    }

    void swap(leaks_memory & lm) noexcept {
        std::swap(lm.memory, memory);
        std::swap(lm.size_of_memory, size_of_memory);
    }

    leaks_memory(leaks_memory && lm) {
        swap(lm);
    }

    leaks_memory & operator=(leaks_memory lm) {
        swap(lm);
        return *this;
    }

    ~leaks_memory() {
        delete[] memory;
        dennounce();
    }

    int & operator[](size_t index) {
        return memory[index];
    }

    const int & operator[](size_t index) const {
        return memory[index];
    }
private:
    int * memory;
    size_t size_of_memory;

    void announce() const noexcept {
        std::cout << "We created a Leaks Memory!" << std::endl;
    }

    void dennounce() const noexcept {
        std::cout << "We destroyed a Leaks Memory!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now, on their own, these aren't issues, until I write code that looks like this:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<base> base_ptr;
    std::atomic_bool done = false;
    std::thread input_thread{ [&done] {
        std::getline(std::cin, std::string());
        done = true;
    } };
    while (!done) {
        base_ptr = std::make_unique<leaks_memory>(20'000);
    }
    input_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This code leaks 20kb every iteration of the loop, because the `leaks_memory` destructor never gets called!

Now, obviously, I could fix this problem by making an edit to `base`:

```
    virtual ~base() {
        std::cout << "We destroyed a base!" << std::endl;
    }
```

And indeed, if I run the same code after making this change, I no longer have this memory leak.

But what if I'm in a situation where I cannot edit the `base` class? Is there a way to prevent the memory leak without completely altering the design of the executing code?

Comment: Have a `virtual` destructor in the base class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please read the entire prompt. I want to know if it's possible *without* modifying the `base` class. I already know that making `base`'s destructor virtual will fix it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ BTW destructors should always be virtual.

Comment: @Xirema probably not possible without having a virtual destructor in the base class. Virtual destructors are made for this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Not necessarily, it does add a performance penalty.  Any class that might be inherited from should always be virtual.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Not necessarily, there are many cases I don't need virtual destructors and want to avoid a vtable being generated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, but then you need to to take care of this "by hand".

Comment: @Xirema Well, then the answer is: No, it's not possible without changing the base class.

Comment: If you are dealing with a situation where you need to use an *external* class as your base (say vendor/library etc.) and they have explicitly declared the destructor as *non-virtual* it's a hint to you, don't derive from this! Use composition instead...

Comment: All your base are belong to... nah.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior, not a memory leak. You can get rid of it if you use a custom deleter with your smart pointer (may have to use shared_ptr instead, or your own brand of unique_ptr).

Comment: @Xirema - The code you posted has undefined behavior.  So let's say the undefined behavior was to call your `leaks_memory` destructor -- does that change the fact the behavior is still undefined, even if it "worked"?

Comment: @Nim It might be another kind of hint, namely "It didn't crash on us so we shipped it". This implies "do not derive", and also "do not compose" and generally "avoid like plague".

Comment: @n.m. Speaking as someone who works as a Product Developer, I can attest that "avoid like plague" is practically *never* an option. =D I think your comment might be closest to a canonical answer for me though, so if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 smart pointers have custom deleters that somewhat relax the requirement to have a virtual destructot at a root of every hierarchy.

Unfortunately this feature is not easy to use, because the type of the deleter is a template parameter of both shared_ptr and unique_ptr. So in order to hide the type of the final object, one needs a bit of type erasure:

```
void derived_deleter(base* p) { delete static_cast<derived*>(p); }

std::unique_ptr<base, decltype(&derived_deleter)> base_ptr (new derived, derived_deleter);
```

There seems to be no way to use std::make_unique.

Comment: This works well with `base_ptr(nullptr,nullptr)` and then `base_ptr.swap(temp_base_ptr)` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you can live with a `const` reference, might be to use the ["most important const"](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

The following will create a reference to the base, but will call the derived destructor.

```
leaks_memory factory()
{
    return leaks_memory(20'000);
}

int main()
{
    //std::unique_ptr<base> base_ptr;
    std::atomic_bool done = false;
    std::thread input_thread{[&done] {
        std::getline(std::cin, std::string());
        done = true;
    }};
    while (!done) {
        //base_ptr = std::make_unique<leaks_memory>(20'000);
        const base& base_const_ref = factory();
    }
    input_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```